# Upgrade Ubuntu without GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, usb

I have a very odd setup and I would like to upgrade my Ubuntu installation while maintaining this setup. Here's the situation: My actual HDD (let's call it "sda") has a Windows installation on it, which I would like to keep untouched. I also have a Live USB of Ubuntu 15.04 ("sdb"), and an outdated USB with a full installation of Ubuntu and disabled journaling ("sdc").

I would like to do the following process:

1. Boot the system from sdb.
2. Upgrade sdc to 15.04 using the mounted installation in sdb, while both **maintaining the existing /home files and installed packages on sdc and either installing GRUB to sdc or not installing it at all, keeping sda untouched all the same**.
3. If GRUB was not installed to sdc, then load sdb up and install GRUB to sdc from the terminal where its destination can be specified.

I know how to handle steps 1 and 3, I need help with executing step 2. Please bless me with your wisdom!